# iOS: Adding on/off control for only first two cells in the Grouped UITableView

Tags: ios

I need to create a Grouped UITableView like showing in the below picture. I created a Grouped UITableView in XIB and added the relevant code as per below code.

It's a simple grouped UITableview.

I like to know, how can i add On/OFF Switch like Button (Pls refer the image Security header) only those first two cells and remaining will be UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator?

Could someone guide me on this please?

[image: Reference Image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSArray *arrTemp1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Quick Logon",@"Stay Logged On", nil];
    NSArray *arrTemp2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Notifications",@"Text Messaging",@"Family Members",@"Social Media",nil];
    NSArray *arrTemp3 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Payment Accounts",nil];
    NSArray *arrTemp4 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Phone Nickname",@"Version",nil];

    NSDictionary *temp =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrTemp1,@"Security",arrTemp2,@"Profile & Preferences", arrTemp3,@"Payment Preferences", arrTemp4,@"About",  nil];

    self.tableContents =temp;

    NSLog(@"table %@",self.tableContents);
    NSLog(@"table with Keys %@",[self.tableContents allKeys]);
    self.sortedKeys =[[self.tableContents allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"sorted %@",self.sortedKeys);

}

#pragma mark Table Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [self.sortedKeys count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
    return [listData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add On/OFF Switch to the cell propotype and show/hide when it needed.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];


    cell.switch.hidden = indexPath.secton > 0; 
    cell.accessoryType = indexPath.secton > 0 ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create two different prototype cells in your xib with two different identifiers. In cellForRowAtIndexPath:, dequeue the one you want based on the section,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    static NSString *SwitchCellIdentifier = @"SwitchCellIdentifier";

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
    UITableViewCell * cell;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SwitchCellIdentifier];
        // configure the cell;
        return cell;
    }else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
        // configure the cell;
        return cell;
   }
}
```